# Problem with Volume and Parallelepiped

Tags: graphics3d, linear-algebra

This worked (copied from the documentation), and gave correct image with Graphics3D.

```
R = Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}];
Volume[R]
```

Using different vectors, this also gave the correct image.

```
Options[myText] = {Background -> White, Padding -> 1, 
   FrameStyle -> None};
myText[s_, pos_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Text[Framed[Style[s, 12], Background -> OptionValue[Background], 
   FrameMargins -> OptionValue[Padding], 
   FrameStyle -> OptionValue[FrameStyle]], pos]

Graphics3D[{
  Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 2}}],
  Blue, Thick,
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 2}}],
  myText["(1,1,0)", {.5, .5, 0}],
  myText["(0,1,1)", {0, .5, .5}],
  myText["(-1,1,2)", {-0.5, 0.5, 1}]
  }, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

However, the Volume command did not work.

```
R = Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 2}}];
Volume[R]
```

Giving me this message:

Volume::reg: Parallelepiped[{0,0,0},{{1,1,0},{0,1,1},{-1,1,2}}] is not a correctly specified region. >>

Is this a bug?

**Update:** Thanks to ilian, I've seen my mistake. Adding a viewpoint makes it clear they are dependent.

```
Graphics3D[{
  Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 2}}],
  Blue, Thick,
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 2}}],
  myText["(1,1,0)", {.5, .5, 0}],
  myText["(0,1,1)", {0, .5, .5}],
  myText["(-1,1,2)", {-0.5, 0.5, 1}]
  }, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300, ViewPoint -> {0, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: As documented, `Parallelepiped` requires the directions to be linearly independent. Degenerate parallelepipeds are not considered valid regions per `RegionQ`.

Comment: @ilian Great answer! I just assumed looking at the image that they were linearly independent, but they are not. Rotating the image reveals that they are not linearly independent as does `A = Transpose[{{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 2}}]`, followed by `MatrixForm[RowReduce[A]]`. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Also, the fact that the sides weren't in different colors should have been an indication to me that they were dependent.

Comment: or `Det@matrix`

Comment: You're trying things out in 3D; exploit the interactivity! Don't just look; spin things around a bit. If it looks flat, it may well be flat (and as rewi notes `Det[]` is the canonical way to check).